# Drop Down Control at bottom of page causes values not to show unless you scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I've got some control filters on the left side of a page.  Issue is some of these pages have a lot of filters and here is where my issue starts.  If I have specifically a drop down control at the bottom of the page and I click on it, its values move towards the bottom of the page and the user cannot see them without having to scroll.

I am using the chosen plug in but I'm not sure it is a chosen issue or a css issue or just normal functionality.

Here's what happens visually:

[image]

Then it almost looks like the selection is for a project because the chosen library's input box is placed right next to my "Project" filter, and all the values for a "Company" are hidden unless you scroll down the page.

Sample markup, please note most of it is auto generated by the chosen library:

```
    <tr>
                                                            <td class="labelField">
                                                                <span id="MainContent_lblCompany0">Co. Group:</span>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td class="valueField">
                                                                <select name="ctl00$MainContent$ddlCorpGroups" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContent$ddlCorpGroups\',\'\')', 0)" id="MainContent_ddlCorpGroups" title="Select Corp. Group." class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Select Corporate Group..." style="width: 125px; display: none;">
            <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
            <option value="11">BMW</option>
            <option value="12">Caterpillar</option>
            <option value="8">Chrysler</option>
            <option value="3">Ford</option>
            <option value="35">Getrag</option>
            <option value="5">GM</option>
            <option value="17">Navistar</option>
            <option value="56">TESLA</option>
            <option value="4">ThyssenKrupp</option>
            <option value="27">ZF</option>

        </select>
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" style="width: 175px;" title="Select Corp. Group." id="MainContent_ddlCorpGroups_chosen">
<a class="chosen-single chosen-default" tabindex="-1"><span>Select Corporate Group...</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chosen-drop"><div class="chosen-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off"></div><ul class="chosen-results"><li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="1">BMW</li><li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="2">Caterpillar</li><li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="3">Chrysler</li><li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="4">Ford</li><li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="5">Getrag</li><li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="6">GM</li><li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="7">Navistar</li><li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="8">TESLA</li><li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="9">ThyssenKrupp</li><li class="active-result" style="" data-option-array-index="10">ZF</li></ul></div></div>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
```

Comment: Is this jQuery mobile? Looks like a listview with filter set to `true`!

Comment: No it's simply an asp.net drop down list, using the chosen library to make it look more appealing.  http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: can you show your code which you tried sofar?

Comment: Please share some code

Answer (score 4):

This is a CSS issue. An ancestor element of the dropdown (likely to be the container of your form) is set to `overflow: hidden`.

The fix is to, 1. in the rare case where it's feasible, remove this CSS property or 2. code some hack which moves the drop down from its current position in the DOM to become a child of the `body` element.

Here's a long discussion you might find useful: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/86

Comment: I've already seen that post and am still not certain how to fix this issue.  The select box is on a aspx page and not on a dialog box.

Comment: The select box being on an aspx page or inside a dialog box are not mutually exclusive... at the end of all the server-side processing, the resulting html created has the issue described. Without any further information (such as a code snippet) you can't get any more valuable advice.

Comment: What type of snippet would you like?  Its simply a select box, load it with say 50 values, place it on your page, and click on it.  All I'd be doing is pasting a whole slew of values in a drop down control.

Comment: The HTML surrounding the select box and their corresponding CSS (the values aren't important).

Comment: i added some sample code, please note above this filter is a lot more filter, causing this filter to be at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't provide any code, example or attempt to solve your problem with [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) but from testing the demo or looking at the API, I can't find any custom form element that'd open toward the top as a native select would do in most if not all browsers so maybe it wasn't planned in this plugin.

**[select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)**, another plugin, is recommended in an issue about [overflow: hidden](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/86) (more active plugin, etc).
The demo successfully opens dropdown toward the top when there's no sufficient place toward bottom and seems to also work fine with keyboard (good sign). From an accessibility point of view, none of them seems to use WAI-ARIA but I didn't test them in real situation and if needed a fix could be as simple as an off-viewport native select bound to the custom one

Comment: I think we may end up going with select2.  i was looking at this solution for quite some time.

Comment: There is a twitter bootstrap specific one also if you happen to use it  -  https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select

Answer (score 2):

I Would use `$.scrollTo()` function, and when the dropdown opens, automatically scoll to it's location (plus some extra pixels... so it would look better.

Comment: Right but where am I calling this, I dont just want to go to each control and in its change event call this.  I'd have to do this statically knowing in advance which controls I need to set this to.

Comment: You can call this only from the change event of your last (bottom most) dropdown. 

Or, you can invest a bit more, and bind to the event that opens the dropdown, and then calculate it's size & position, to understand if it's all visible (compare it to the window size, and the scroll position...), and only apply the $.scrollTo() if needed... although is seems kind of an overkill...